# Converting .doc to pure text using Python

Tags: python, ms-word, text-extraction

I am trying to use textract to convert my .doc files to pure text.

```
import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/file.extension')
```

But I am getting this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Comment: which version of textract you are using?

Comment: @Tanu I am using 1.6.1

Comment: Have you installed all other dependencies successfully ? - `apt-get install python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev antiword unrtf poppler-utils pstotext tesseract-ocr flac ffmpeg lame libmad0 libsox-fmt-mp3 sox libjpeg-dev swig libpulse-dev`(for Ubuntu). Working fine on my system.

Comment: @tanu I was unaware that I needed these other dependencies for Textract. I have Windows, should i still install them?

Comment: Refer this - http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#ubuntu-debian

Comment: [check this](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#don-t-see-your-operating-system-installation-instructions-here).

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the Python file you are trying to run is not named `textract.py`.

If that's the name, you will get the error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process'
> ```