# Textract - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process' - pointing to non existent file

Tags: python, python-2.7, debian

I am trying to run a few speed tests on various ways of getting text out of .doc, .docx and .pdf files and came across `textract` for Python which looked promising. I have installed `textract` and all its dependencies on Kali Linux (Debian), i am just trying to run a simple test:

```
import os
import sys
import textract 

text = textract.process("/home/owain/Documents/Documents/file.doc")
```

I named the file `textract.py` which i then found out breaks things: [Converting .doc to pure text using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916890/converting-doc-to-pure-text-using-python)

the error i am getting

> ```
> kali@Kali:~/Scripts/TestScripts$ time python tttt.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "tttt.py", line 3, in <module>
>     import textract   
>   File "/home/owain/Scripts/TestScripts/textract.py", line 4, in <module>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'process'
> ```

So i removed `textract`, deleted the textract.py file and re-installed `textract`. This didnt work as i am still getting the same above error, even with that file not existing anymore. Unsure where to go from here so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a file called `textract` which collides with the actual dependency name.